# JavaScript search for elements

Tags: javascript

How on JavaScript without Jquery search for items?
Example:

```
<div open="yes">Test</div>
$('[open="yes"]');
```

How to find this item in javascript without Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) which returns element based on CSS selectors. You'll want to use `document.querySelectorAll` if you want it to return more than one element.

```
console.log(document.querySelector('[open=yes]'));
```

> Returns the first element within the document (using depth-first
>   pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that matches the
>   specified group of selectors